# reading tabstops as 4 whitespaces using textscan

Tags: matlab, textscan, tabstop

Is it possible to tell MATLAB's `textscan` to import tabs as four whitespaces? Currently it's replacing a tab with just one whitespace:

```
raw = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n','Whitespace','');
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why not do it in two steps (the second being "find and replace" `\t` by 4 spaces)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Dev-iL,

I thought maybe there is some option to add to textscan, but now I added as you suggested another line of code:

```
raw = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n','Whitespace','');
raw = regexprep(raw{1},'\t','    ');
```